# What is the best way to create objects from several classes and insert values?

Tags: java, oop

I have a class called **Features** that looks like this,

```
public class Features {
    public String opSys;
    public String chipset;
    public String cpu;
    public String gpu;

    public Features(String opSys,String chipset,String cpu,String gpu,) {
        this.opSys = opSys;
        this.chipset = chipset;
        this.cpu = cpu;
        this.gpu = gpu;
    }
}
```

And i have another called **Camera** like this,

```
public class Camera {
    public String primary;
    public String features;
    public String video;
    public String secondary;

    public Camera(String primary, String features, String video, String secondary){
        this.primary = primary;
        this.features = features;
        this.video = video;
        this.secondary = secondary;
    }
}
```

And i'm trying to create a phone using these two classes in a class called **Phone**. How do i do this and pass the values?

Comment: Can you show the class `Phone` for better understanding of your issue?

Comment: `public Phone(Features features, Camera camera) { this.features = features; this.Camera = camera;}`.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin could you explain your idea better? AFAIK a Java class cannot extends from two or more classes.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It would be better to have a base class called Phone and inherits it from it since it is a phone functionality

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I don't follow you. Ok, I have a `Phone` class, then `Features` should extend from `Phone`, and `Camera` too?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No not multiple inheritance. Features and Camera only extends to Phone

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin that's what I'm saying: `class Phone {} class Features extends Phone {} class Camera extends Phone {}`. And my question is still the same: **why?**

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin: a Camera should not extend Phone, a Phone can have a camera, there's a logical difference

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin - he needs to use *composition* not *inheitance*.

Comment: @k9yosh: don't set all your variables public. Declare them as private and add mutators (setters and getters) to your classes.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin, I don't think he's suppose to `extend` either `Camera` or `Features`. A `Phone` IS *NOT* A `Camera`, and it's definitely *NOT* A `Features`. A `Phone` **HAS A** `Camera` and `Features`. He should have instances of those Objects inside his `Phone`.

Comment: @all_people_who_tag_me right2x my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ehm... the "same" way like `Camera` and `Features` ... :)

```
public class Phone {
    private Camera camera;
    private Features features;

    public Phone(Camera camera, Features features){
        this.camera = camera;
        this.features = features;
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera newCamera){
        this.camera = newCamera;
    }

    public void setFeatures(Features newFeatures){
        this.features = newFeatures;
    }

    public Camera getCamera(){
        return camera;
    }

    public Features getFeatures(){
        return features;
    }

}
```

then... `new Phone(new Camera(....), new Features(...)` ...

and your homework is finished.. :P

Comment: True.. But then also have Camera and Feature(s) are revised

Comment: public String primary... public String features.. all fields/properties are public in he's code..

Comment: That doesn't mean it is right and you should follow. Instead, provide an explanation why that's bad in Java along with your answer.

Comment: true! "do it right or do nothing.." :D i have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your Phone class can contain `Features` and `Camera` , then you can use setters or constructor to set values for those fields:-

```
class Phone{

private Camera camera;
private Features features;

//use constructor to set values

public Phone(Camera camera, Features features){
this.camera=camera;
this.features= features
}

public Phone(String opSys, String chipset, String cpu, String gpu, String primary, String features, String video, String secondary){
camera=new Camera(opSys, chipset, cpu, gpu);
features= new Features(primary,features, video, secondary);
}

//or use setters to set value

public setCamera(Camera camera){
// set values
this.camera=camera;
}

public setFeatures(Features features){
//set values
this.features=features;
}

}
```

There is also a typo in your source, remove the extra `,` from the contructor parameters of `Features`